# Video Out through USB (or other means)

Tags: usb, fpga, video, compression

For an medium-high speed ADC converter, my FPGA is currently receiving 16-bit samples at 54 MHz over an LVDS interface (4 differential signal lines plus 1 differential clock signal). These are video/camera signals.

Now, I need to consider how I can get the image from the FPGA to the PC. I have a micro-controller and a USB-OTG interface. But USB is 480 Mbit/s, and probably down to 35 MB/s effectively (or less), which is not high enough for 16 bits 1.5 MPixels @ 54 frames/sec. That would be 162 MB/sec, far too high for USB 2.0. Am I forced to use USB 3.0? I really did want to get the raw images out to the PC. I also could conceivably perform loss-less compression on the FPGA.

The second question is how to stream this data out of the FPGA. I could buffer the ADC-data in external RAM, or I could set up an interface to the micro-controller, or even directly drive output signals on a port. Either way, what options do I have w.r.t. large streams of data?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want to use a microcontroller for 162MB/s... Really? What microcontroller exactly were you planning on using?

Comment: No, not directly, of course. However, the uController needs to be in a supervising role.

Comment: Can you add some other interface specifically for video? HDMI or something?

Comment: There are HD video capture cards, Black Magic I think make some 1080p60 / HDMI / HD-SDI ones, but it's a big ask for uncompressed / lossless video as the bandwidth is at the limit of what a lot of hardware is designed for in any sustained manner.

Comment: ...on the other hand, compressed data can be made insanely small, 1080p30 pictures can be squirted down ethernet at 1Mbit/s with a decent H.264 codec in surprisingly good quality.

Comment: One project I'm working on uses a TI DaVinci processor which is a DSP-core to handle the video coding (LVDS -> H.264 / MPEG4 / MJPEG) and an ARM-core supervising running Linux.

Comment: You cna foget the USB2, there is no way you can get that to work without some very strong compression, but you can easily use a USB3 board such as this one https://www.arrow.com/en/products/beusb3.0/arrow-development-tools/#page-1 that can be 'hacked' to connect to any FPGA board, or buy one of the other ones availabe on the market. With that you can get up to 100MB/s not more (militation of the Cypress CPU)

Comment: To be honest with you, I would go with PCIE instead of USB to make sure you will not have any surprises later on. The PCIe boards are pretty common and you can get one at a decent price and with a standard connector (FMC) to connect to your ADC, and even with a 4 channle PCIe gen1, you get a far better performance than USB2/3 can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bandwidth requirement is wayyyy beyond USB2 (by a factor of 4-5x).  Unless your images have some special features you can take advantage of, lossless compression is only going to get you a 50% (ish) improvement, so that's not going to work.

You have to either increase your available bandwidth (USB3) or reduce the bandwidth requirement (ie resolution, frame rate, bit depth or some combination).

Regarding the FPGA->USB interface, if you want something easy to get going, try [Opal Kelly](https://www.opalkelly.com/products/xem6310/)'s boards - they have done the USB3/FPGA interfacing bit for you and you can concentrate on the bit that interests you.  (I have no connection with OK other than as a happy user of their stuff.)

Otherwise, you need a micro with the USB interface on it and some FIFO-like hardware+DMA engine so that the micro is (as you say) only supervising the data transfers.  [Cypress](http://www.cypress.com/products/usb-controllers) make some.  [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT600.html) also (although they are micros, you don't have to touch the innards, you can pretend they are a FIFO and the data 'magically' appears at the PC).